# How do you screenshot an ARKit camera view?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

Looking for a way to capture a screenshot or video of the ARScene without the buttons and other subviews

Traditional screen capture captures everything visible on the screen including UI controls

Comment: do you know how to take a screenshot of a specific area in the view?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ARSCNViews have a built in snapshot method that returns a UIImage of the ARScene

So in Objective-C you could do:

```
UIImage *image = [sceneView snapshot];
```

and in Swift

```
var image = sceneView.snapshot()
```

Comment: do you know how to take a screenshot of a specific area in the view?

Comment: @Harsh Sorry to say that I do not. If you can find the CGRect of what you want to screenshot in your view, you might be able to use that data to crop the resulting picture.